# Connection error to a SMTP server with python

Tags: python, email, error-handling, connection

So I tried to run this code. It's basically just an email sender, but I'm getting this error:

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError

I'm getting error when I'm trying to connect to the SMTP server. the rest seems ok from what I see.

Thanks for helping!!!

```
import smtplib
import sys
print("Hello there! This is a program to send emails. please enter your 
email provider: Google. Yahoo. Comcast. AT&T. Verizon OR Outlock") #Email 
provider
emailProvider = input()
if emailProvider == 'Google':
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
elif emailProvider == 'Yahoo':
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.yahoo.com', 587)
elif emailProvider == 'Comcast':
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.comcast.net', 587)
elif emailProvider == 'AT&T':
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smpt.mail.att.net', 465)
elif emailProvider == 'Verison':
     smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.verizon.net', 465)
elif emailProvider == 'Outlock':
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()

if emailProvider == 'Google':
    smtpObj.starttls()
elif emailProvider == 'Yahoo':
    smtpObj.starttls()
elif emailProvider == 'Comcast':
    smtpObj.starttls()
elif emailProvider == 'Outlock':
    smtpObj.starttls()

try:
    print("Please enter your password:") #login
    password = input()
    print("Please enter your email address.")
    address = input()
    smtpObj.login(address, password )
except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
    print("Wrong password/email")
    sys.exit()

print("Good. Your connected.")
print("Now lets send an email! please enter the recipient email address")
otherEmail = input()
print("Please enter YOUR Email address")
myEmail = input()
print("Please enter the subject.")
subject = input()
print("Please enter the message")
message = input()
smtpObj.sendmail(myEmail,otherEmail, #Sending email
'Subject: Test \n''This Is just a test')
{}

smtpObj.quit() #Disconnecting from server
```

Comment: Try for google but before you do that, do not forget to ALLOW LESS SECURE APPS in the google account settings, here --> https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Is it one provider that doesn't work or all?? Please also provide the full stacktrace for the error